# Return index from lookup table allowing for nulls and not found

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the index in a lookup table allowing for elements not found and elements not existing (null).

As an example, in the test data below, the variable "A" would map to the "A" in the lookup table and return an index of 0 (the position of "A" in the lookup table)

I was looking at using the searchsorted function, but its not explained whether a 0 or N is returned.

"If there is no suitable index, return either 0 or N (where N is the length of a)."

From the below, the data I would like to return is:
[0,1,2,3,2]

0 - match on A,
1 - match on B,
2 - not found hence Else,
3 - no value hence NULL,
2 - not found hence else.

with the rules:

If match return index of match,
if NaN return NULL,
if not found return else.

```
testData = np.array(['A','B','B ',NAN,'Other'])
testLookup =np.array(['A','B','ELSE','NULL'])

>>> np.searchsorted(testLookup,testData)
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want. What do you want to lookup where?

Comment: @jpp how are you getting the `index` values `3` and `2` for `' '` and `Other` ?

Comment: Updated with answers to questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy isn't designed for mixed type arrays. But if you are intent on using NumPy you can just convert your values as appropriate via Boolean indexing *before* using `np.searchsorted`.

Just remember to specify `dtype=object` to avoid your `np.nan` values being auto-converted to strings.

```
testData = np.array(['A','B','B ',np.nan,'Other'], dtype=object)
testLookup = np.array(['A','B','ELSE','NULL'])

arr = testData.copy()
nulls = np.array([x != x for x in arr])
arr[nulls] = 'NULL'
arr[~np.in1d(arr, testLookup[:2]) & ~nulls] = 'ELSE'  # or use np.isin

res = np.searchsorted(testLookup, arr)

# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2], dtype=int64)
```